# I want my .py code will read the excel file globally

Tags: python

My code is

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
os.chdir('H:\python')
file_name='H:\python\\test.xlsx'
```

But i don't want to specify the filename in .py file. Is there any option in python to read the file globally.

Comment: What do you mean by "read the file globally" ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. by accepting an input from user. So, use `input` method to accept a path to the excel file and then use that.

the following code will work

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = input()
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

EDIT: Adding one more way to do this. write the following code in a python file. Assuming file name is `excel_reader.py`

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

use the following command to give a file via command line as argument.

```
python excel_reader.py "C:\path_to_the_excel_file"
```

Comment: please, don't make people use `input()`

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, updated the code to use command line arguments .

Comment: looks great! the command line call is probably even more useful with `-i` flag

Comment: I think one can do `python -i excel_reader.py C://path_to_the_excel_file//file.xls` - this leaves the interpreter open after `df` is initialised.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, so, i have to use getopt module to get the file name right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173222/discussion-between-inaflash-and-evgeny-pogrebnyak).